# Ошибка добавления пользователя в бд

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

```swift
import FirebaseAuth
import Foundation

class MainViewViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentUserId:String = ""
    private var handler = AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    init() {
        self.handler = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener{[weak self] _, user in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.currentUserId = user?.uid ?? ""
            }
        }
    }
    
    public var isSignedIn:Bool {
        return Auth.auth().currentUser != nil
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде как, каждый раз, когда пользователь входит и выходит в систему, должна срабатывать функция `addStateListener`.

Как решать, что делать?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainViewViewModel : ObservableObject{
@Published var currentUserId:String = ""
//private var handler = AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

init(){
    let handler = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener{[weak self] _, user in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self?.currentUserId = user?.uid ?? ""

        }
        
    }
}
```